なぜ質問の答えを回答しないのですか？ソース見せないと回答できないって、アイデア盗むのが目的に見えました。
ブラックリストに入れる方法教えてください。
環境、ソース、エラーメッセージなど関係ないのは明らかです。

例えばこんな記事を読んで考えてみてください。プログラミングの正しい質問方法をプロが体系的に解説, 【2024年版】プログラミング質問サイトおすすめ11選！質問の仕方も紹介, プログラミング初心者におすすめな質問サイト13選【質問の仕方も解説】 それから前の質問のコメントに紹介したようにこのサイトのヘルプ記事で問題を再現出来る最小限のサンプルコードを提示してくださいと書いてあるのを読んでいないようですね。再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方 貴方のプログラムについて一字一句変えずに全てを提示する必要はありませんよ。問題を他の人が把握・再現出来る程度で良いのです。

サイトの使い方に関するご質問は「スタック・オーバーフロー　メタ」までお願いします https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/
